# Como criar esta hierarquia de classes?

Tags: java, classes, herança

Nesse exercício, eu tenho que criar uma classe dentro de outra classe ou são classes independentes?

- Um animal contém um nome, comprimento,
  número de patas (o padrão é 4), uma cor, ambiente
  e uma velocidade (em m/s).
- Um peixe é um animal, tem 0 patas, o seu ambiente
  é o mar (padrão), cor cinzenta (padrão). Além disso,
  o peixe tem como característica: barbatanas e
  cauda;
- Um mamífero é um animal, o seu ambiente padrão
  é a terra e tem como característica: pelo em todo ou
  em parte do corpo;
- Um urso é um mamífero, cor castanho e o seu
  alimento preferido é o mel e com pelo em todo
  corpo.

Codifique as classes animal, peixe, mamífero e urso
considerando todas elas possuem um construtor
que recebe o nome.

Comment: É um exercício sobre herança. Peixe e mamífero derivam de animal e urso deriva de mamífero que por sua vez é derivado de animal.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi isso é um exercício de herança. Sim, elas são classes independentes, porém algumas classes herdam atributos e métodos de outras classes. Peixe herda da classe animal, mamífero também herda da classe animal e urso herda de mamífero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse parece ser um exercício de POO sobre herança, não é criar uma classe dentro de outra, mas sim estender as classes filhas com a classe mãe. Eu implementei uma versão própria aqui com base na suas descrições.

Essa é a classe base, deixei todos os atributos como String para facilitar.

Animal.java

```
public class Animal {
    protected String nome, comprimento, patas, cor, ambiente, velocidade, caracteristica, alimentoPreferido;

    public Animal(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;

        this.comprimento = "0m";
        this.patas = "0";
        this.cor = "Nenhuma";
        this.ambiente = "Nenhum";
        this.velocidade = "0m/s";
        this.caracteristica = "Nenhuma";
        this.alimentoPreferido = "Nenhum";
    }

    public String getNome() { return nome; }

    public void setNome(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }

    public String getComprimento() { return comprimento; }

    public void setComprimento(String comprimento) { this.comprimento = comprimento; }

    public String getPatas() { return patas; }

    public void setPatas(String patas) { this.patas = patas; }

    public String getCor() { return cor; }

    public void setCor(String cor) { this.cor = cor; }

    public String getAmbiente() { return ambiente; }

    public void setAmbiente(String ambiente) { this.ambiente = ambiente; }

    public String getVelocidade() { return velocidade; }

    public void setVelocidade(String velocidade) { this.velocidade = velocidade; }

    public String getCaracteristica() { return caracteristica; }

    public void setCaracteristica(String caracteristica) { this.caracteristica = caracteristica; }

    public String getAlimentoPreferido() { return alimentoPreferido; }

    public void setAlimentoPreferido(String alimentoPreferido) { this.alimentoPreferido = alimentoPreferido;    }
}
```

Subclasse que estende animal herdando seus atributos e métodos.

Peixe.java

```
public class Peixe extends Animal {
    public Peixe(String nome) {
        super(nome);

        this.comprimento = "15cm";
        this.patas = "0";
        this.cor = "Cinzenta";
        this.ambiente = "Mar";
        this.velocidade = "2m/s";
        this.caracteristica = "Barbatanas e Cauda";
        this.alimentoPreferido = "Algas";
    }
}
```

Subclasse que estende animal herdando seus atributos e métodos.

Mamifero.java

```
public class Mamifero extends Animal {
    public Mamifero(String nome) {
        super(nome);

        this.ambiente = "Terra";
        this.caracteristica = "Pelo em todo ou em parte do corpo";
    }
}
```

Subclasse que estende Mamifero herdando seus atributos e métodos.

Urso.java

```
public class Urso extends Mamifero {
    public Urso(String nome) {
        super(nome);

        this.comprimento = "1m";
        this.patas = "4";
        this.cor = "Castanho";
        this.velocidade = "1m/s";
        this.caracteristica = "Pelo em todo corpo";
        this.alimentoPreferido = "Mel";
    }
}
```

E uma classe para testar Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Animal("Animal Base");
        Peixe peixe = new Peixe("Nemo");
        Mamifero mamifero = new Mamifero("Mamifero Base");
        Urso urso = new Urso("Zé Colmeia");

        System.out.println(animal.getNome());
        System.out.println(peixe.getPatas());
        System.out.println(mamifero.getCaracteristica());
        System.out.println(urso.getAlimentoPreferido());
    }
}
```